# i need help to bind html table using DataTable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

table code like this:

i need help to bind table with database table and 
display data in table format Bind Table Using Data Table With Link Button
given code is aspx file code i need axpx.cs file code
`Table Code:`

```html
    <table  border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Main Action</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <%
                if (dt != null && dt.rows.count>0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in dt.rows)
                    {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinlEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"/>
                    &nbsp;|
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"/>
                </td>

                <td><%# Eval("name") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("emailid") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("mobilenumber") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkAction" runat="server" Text="Enable"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                    }
                }
            %>
```

Comment: what your problem?

Comment: i need help to perform binding with html table

Answer (score 0):

you can try as follows

in Aspx page

```
<table style="width: 50%; text-align: center; background-color: skyblue;">  
            <tr>  
                <td align="center">  
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DBDataPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>  
                </td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>
```

in aspx.cs

```
SqlDataAdapter da;  
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
        StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();  

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
                BindData();  
        }  

        private void BindData()  
        {  
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();  
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=MYPC\SqlServer2k8;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MyCompany";  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", con);  
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            da.Fill(ds);  
            con.Open();  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            con.Close();  

            htmlTable.Append("<table border='1'>");  
            htmlTable.Append("<tr style='background-color:green; color: White;'><th>Customer ID.</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Contact No</th></tr>");  

            if (!object.Equals(ds.Tables[0], null))  
            {  
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  
                {  

                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)  
                    {  
                        htmlTable.Append("<tr style='color: White;'>");  
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Name"] + "</td>");  
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Email"] + "</td>");  
                        htmlTable.Append("<td>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Mobile"] + "</td>");  
                        htmlTable.Append("<td><a>Action</a></td>");  
                        htmlTable.Append("</tr>");  
                    }  
                    htmlTable.Append("</table>");  
                    DBDataPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    htmlTable.Append("<tr>");  
                    htmlTable.Append("<td align='center' colspan='4'>There is no Record.</td>");  
                    htmlTable.Append("</tr>");  
                }  
            }  
        }
```

you have to write logic to perform actions.

I would suggest better go with Gridview and override CSS if you want any specific styles to be applied.

Comment: sir without using asp.net control

Comment: thank you sir but i need like this   public DataSet ds = null; in my cs page